# Running batch files in GIt from Jenkins

Tags: git, batch-file, jenkins

I have a few .bat files in Git (say a.bat, b.bat and c.bat). I want to execute them from Jenkins on a particular schedule on the fly. So basically I want a.bat and b.bat to run every night at 11pm and c.bat at every 2am in the morning.
How can I do that via Jenkins? (I've setup connection to Git repo and I'm looking for the next steps)

Also, is there a way to group the batch files in Jenkins? Since a.bat and b.bat start at the same time (they should run serially though) I can setup a schedule for the group instead of individual batch files. If needed, I can add more batch files to that group in future and no need to set their schedules separately.

And can I parameterize the batch files when I run them (e.g. all three use a network path as a parameter)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create two jobs:

- A job A scheduled every day at 11pm (23 0 * * *)
- A job B scheduled every day at 2am (2 0 * * *)

The two jobs will get the source code from Git:
[image]

The job A will have two Windows batch build steps to launch the a.bat and b.bat scripts.

The job B will have one build step to launch the c.bat script.

These jobs can have one or more parameters to store your network path:

[image]